# My Hard disk is going to be full

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, storage, boot-partition, disk-management

My disk is going to be full because of my system.
I want to take a few space from DATA. I'm on a dual-boot PC with Ubuntu 16.04  and Windows 8.1.

[image: devices]

Comment: Please post the output of the commands `df` and `sudo fdisk -l`, so we can get a better idea of your partitioning. (Copy and paste the text only, not screenshots.)

Comment: I dont know if is possible or not.. but try gparted.. unmount data and resize data..that will create some unallocated memory...if ur ubuntu disk is created shrinking data disk.. then u can extend those ext4 partitions and take them into ubuntu ..

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `sudo apt-get clean`. That should delete some files the system doesn't need anymore (nor do you).